# FragmentStateAdapter throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated after configuration change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-viewpager2

FragmentStateAdapter throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated,

when the device is rotated. How do I resolve this issue ?

```
private inner class PagerAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
        private val ids = LongSparseArray<Media>()

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = adapter.itemCount

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return adapter.source!![position].time
        }

        override fun containsItem(itemId: Long): Boolean {
            return ids[itemId] != null
        }
    }
```

Exception

```java
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Design assumption violated.
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.placeFragmentInViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:270)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:259)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onViewAttachedToWindow(FragmentStateAdapter.java:68)
```

Comment: post your gradle file

Comment: The error log points to an error in method `placeFragmentInViewHolder` in `FragmentStateAdapter` which is missing in your code. Please include that method in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Apparently you have to restore the state of FragmentStateAdapter after a configuration changed in other for the fragments to be restored properly.

Save state

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        model.addState(IDS, pagerAdapter.ids)
        model.addState(LIST, (adapter.source as ListAdapterSource).getList())
    }
```

Restore state

```
private inner class PagerAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
        val ids: LongSparseArray<Media> = model.getState(IDS) ?: LongSparseArray()
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed now in `ViewPager2`

You need to use [**`Version 1.0.0-beta03`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#androidx-deps)

Update the `dependencies` of `ViewPager2`

```
 dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta03'
 }
```

> Bug fixes

- Fix for FragmentStateAdapter issue with transient Fragment state. [b/134246546](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134246546)

Comment: Apparently I get the same issue with ViewPager2 1.0.0 stable release. Not sure why that might be.